# Joining In Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2003

To join two tables is it necessary that both have Primary Key or Some criteria that must match?

For Example

```
SELECT (t1.col1- t2.col2 )as result

FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

is there any way to use joining without match criteria

Answer (score 0):

In the example you used, yes, you are required to have matching values in T1.ID and T2.ID.  Without matching values found between the two tables, the job of joining gets more difficult. Yes, as an example, you could concoct some scheme where a third table is brought into play.  Lets say T1.ID = 1, then T2.ID = Blue, then add T3 which has two fields as a map like F1 = Blue & F2 = 1. You could join T1.ID = T3.F2 then join T2.ID on T3.F1.  But generally speaking - let's keep the DB design easier to understand.